# Blue sky and Red sunset, Why?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, scattering, atmospheric-science

I tried several resources for understanding this phenomena, but none of them were satisfying. I'll citate one from wikipedia (others were also similar):

> Blue light from the sun is scattered more than red so the sky is blue during the day. At sunset the angle of light is very low and the blue light is scattered away completely leaving only the less scattered red.

During sunset, if blue light is almost gone because there are great chance for scattering it away through longer path (larger portion of atmosphere), is not same logic applies on other wavelength lights? And if it is so, why blue light goes "missing" with larger quantities than red light?

I can formulate my question in other way: why light with dominating scattering value in smaller space creates this dominated color (blue in our case) for our eyes and light with neglecting scattering value in larger space creates neglect color (red-orange in our case)?

Comment: Although it seems to be directed at a younger audience, I found this quite helpful in the past: https://spaceplace.nasa.gov/blue-sky/en/ it gives a simple and intuitive explanation imo.

Comment: Thanks for the video, but my question relies on idea which simply is given at 1:56, why other lights aren't also scattered in longer path?

Comment: Are you asking why the scattering cross-section for blue light is bigger than red light?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scattering of blue wavelength and red wavelength in our atmosphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/631399/)

Comment: Question is similar, but answers are not still satisfying for me (don't know where my reasoning fails)

Comment: @Lasha Bukhnikashvili it's all about the wavelength(or frequency). Higher wavelength light waves scatter less than the lower wavelength light waves. Blue, having higher wavelength, scatter more than red.

Comment: You probably want to look at the concept of Rayleigh Scattering.

Answer (score 2):

In the morning and evening the sunlight has to travel longer distance *through the atmosphere* to reach our eyes. By the time it reaches our eyes, the blue light waves, due to it's higher frequency, get's scattered almost completely. Only the red waves, due to its lower frequency and higher wavelength, remains.

During the day time, light has to travel comparitively shorter distance *through the atmosphere.* So the blue light waves, can reach our eyes. But again, its high frequency makes it scatter thereby making the whole sky blue.