# Why do we not see Sun red in daytime?

Tags: visible-light, scattering, atmospheric-science, sun

I have had this question strike to me as when thinking about the reddish colour of sun during sunsets which is happening through rayleigh scattering , the highly energetic wavelength of colours are dispersed over the top and bottom and the light that reaches our eye is of lower wavelengths compared to the scattered light.

But when we see daytime , the same blue light is scattered elsewhere making the sky blue but why does the sun not appear red in this case , the explanation of redness during sunsets/sunrise seems to contradict the observation of sun during daytime to me.
Can someone say where I went wrong in this?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scattering of blue wavelength and red wavelength in our atmosphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/631399/)

Comment: there is an answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/754527/

Comment: ah yes that answers my question it is just that light needs to travel longer distance through atmosphere than the light during daytime , thank you very much @annav